# Как добавить прокси к веббраузеру Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как можно добавить прокси с логином и паролем к коду ниже?

```
from time import sleep
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from seleniumwire import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={UserAgent().random}')
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\aesok\Desktop\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
try:
    driver.get(link)
    sleep(1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={UserAgent().random}')
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.headless = True
params = {
    "options": options,
    "seleniumwire_options": {
        "backend": "default",
        "proxy": {
            "http": full_proxy
        }
    },
}
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    **params,
    executable_path=r'C:\Users\aesok\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
try:
    driver.get(link)
    sleep(1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ очень помог

Comment: Не стоит благодарности. Если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его принятым, поставив галку слева от него.